# When will use reject and catch at the same time for promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

seems we prefer to use catch to handle the exception since the reject function may miss some errors, e.g. in below code the error a is not defined will not be cached.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  console.log(1)
  resolve('successfully')
})
promise
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(a)
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

we prefer to use catch method to catch the errors like below:

```
promise
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(a)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

My question is: are there any solutions that need to use reject and catch method at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They simply *chain* differently.

```
promise.then(foo, bar)
```

Here `bar` will ***not*** handle any errors which may occur in `foo`.

```
promise.then(foo).catch(bar)
```

Here `bar` ***will*** handle any errors occurring in either `promise` or `foo`.

So, yes, sometimes you want one, sometimes you want the other, sometimes you may want both.

```js
function foo() {
  throw 'foo';
}

function bar(err) {
  console.log('Caught', err);
}

Promise.resolve().then(foo, bar);  // Uncaught error
Promise.reject('promise').then(foo, bar);
Promise.resolve().then(foo).catch(bar);
Promise.reject('promise').then(foo).catch(bar);
Promise.resolve().then(foo, bar).catch(bar);
```

A practical example perhaps:

```
someOperation()
  .then(
    result => someOtherFunction(result.value),
    err => {
      console.warn('Operation failed!', err);
      return 'alternative value';
    }
  )
  .then(result => alert('The result is: ' + result))
  .catch(err => console.error('Everything is wrong :(', err);
```

If `someOperation` succeeds, we continue processing its value, otherwise we'll substitute some default value; and if anything anywhere in the entire chain fails, we have a global final error handler.

Comment: I didn't understand the OP's question this way - I think an example showing when you'd use _both_ the onRejected parameter of `then` and `catch` would be worthwhile and maybe a synchronous example.

Comment: @deceze Thanks a lot for your answer! does that means when it is not an error, maybe just an alternative value we may use onRejected method to handle, if it's a real error, something like not defined error, we refer to use catch to handle the error? is that correct?

Comment: @jeff It simply depends on where you expect errors to occur and how you want to handle them.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! you resolved my question, so basically, catch is just another way of onReject method which will handle the errors on the last step , if we need to handle the error in the middle steps, we can use onReject method.